# Add a list of TextViews and ImageViews to an existing RelativeView programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-imageview

I have a `RelativeLayout` with an id of `relative_layout_bottom` that I am trying to add content to it programmatically. I am looping through a `<TextView, ImageView>` dictionary and adding the entries as follows:

I want the left side (align parent left) of the `RelativeLayout` to have a list of `TextViews` going downwards, and the right side (align parent right) of the `RelativeLayout` to have a list of `ImageViews` going downwards like this:

```
|TextView#1               ImageView#1|
|TextView#2               ImageView#2|
|TextView#3               ImageView#3|
|TextView#4               ImageView#4|
|    .                         .     |
|    .                         .     |
|    .                         .     |
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do this though, nothing is showing up for me. I can edit in the code I have currently if anyone cares to see but I'm pretty sure it'd be more useful to come up with a different solution than to fix mine.

Here is my xml, I am only using one TextView and ImageView that I was going to append to? Not sure if it works like that, or if I should programmatically make an individual TextView and ImageView for each entry.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
tools:context="com.brettrosen.atls.activity.Report">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/report_top_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>


 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/report_bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_layout_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_text_bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_notes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
                />



        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
 TextView checkbox_text_bottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_text_bottom);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_bottom);

for (Map.Entry entry : PrearrivalPlan.imageButtonsWithNotes.entrySet()) {

        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) entry.getValue();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(imageButton.getBackground());

        checkbox_text_bottom.append(entry.getValue() + "\n"); // Append the text to the TextView

        ImageView image = new ImageView(Report.this); // Create an imageview
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)image.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        image.setLayoutParams(params);

        relativeLayout.addView(image); // Add it to the layout


    }
```

Comment: @Heyyou Will do, I'll edit my post with what I've done, but keep in mind it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LinLayLeft"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LinLayRight"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

Now u can add your widgets in the respective linearlayout using addview.
```